# MySQL database recovery / missing ibd files

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, frm

I stupidly neglected to create a backup of my database for a project I was working on a year or two ago and my laptop crashed. I pulled the HDD and managed to find the files for the database under mysql/data however there is only FRM files and a db.opt file. I was running XAMPP 3.2.1 at the time and created the db using phpmyadmin.

What steps can I take from here? Using just the frm files results in collation in use and error #1932 table doesn't exist in engine. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can recover the table definitions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlfrm.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: It's possible that all your data for all tables is stored together in the `mysql/data/ibdata1` tablespace file. The frm files are metadata only. If you really used ibd files (one per table), that's where the data was. If you don't have the files, your data is gone.